# Problem adding content when adding a new site in multisite

Tags: wordpress

Trying to add and tag posts with Type when creating a new site in a multisite WP. I got code in theme which registers the CPT's and code in plugin which adds the example posts. This kinda feels backward to me.

What's the best way to go about adding content to newly created sites in a multisite?

Tried to add code in plugin. Didn't work, probably because the CPT's were not added yet. Adding it to the theme worked but it seemed to trigger every time I manually added new Types to my CPT, which gave me extra copies of the examples.

Running the function from a standalone php script works fine, so I figure it's a timing problem. IE this function is run before CPT's and taxonomy is added.

```php
        function sldb_prtl_add_terms(){
                                /* Register terms used for grouping articles in hardware form*/
                                $hardware_term=wp_insert_term('Hårdvara', 'sldb_prtl_artikeltyp');
                                if(is_wp_error($hardware_term)){
                                        $hardware_term = get_term_by('name', 'Hårdvara', 'sldb_prtl_artikeltyp',ARRAY_A);
                                }
                                wp_insert_term('Möss', 'sldb_prtl_artikeltyp', array('parent'=>$hardware_term['term_id']));
                                $example_address_id = get_page_by_title('Exempelartikel', ARRAY_A, 'sldb_prtl_artikel');
                                $parent_term_id = get_term_by('name', 'Möss', 'sldb_prtl_artikeltyp', ARRAY_A);
                                wp_set_post_terms($example_address_id['ID'], $parent_term_id['term_id'], 'sldb_prtl_artikeltyp');
        }
        add_action('wp_insert_site', 'sldb_prtl_add_terms');
```

I expected the code to add types the above types ONCE when establishing a new site without fear that it will run again.

Answer (score 0):

Did a dirty workaround, since information regarding this is scarce (or I'm just searching the wrong keywords).

Changed the hook to 'init' with a priority of 20 and wrapped the contents of the function within an if statement that I add after first run.

```
    function sldb_prtl_add_terms(){
        if(!get_option('initial_terms_added')){

                // Register terms used for grouping articles in hardware form
                $hardware_term=wp_insert_term('Hårdvara', 'sldb_prtl_artikeltyp');
                wp_insert_term('Möss', 'sldb_prtl_artikeltyp', array('parent'=>$hardware_term['term_id']));
                $example_article_id = get_page_by_title('Exempelartikel', ARRAY_A, 'sldb_prtl_artikel');
                                $parent_term_id = get_term_by('name', 'Möss', 'sldb_prtl_artikeltyp', ARRAY_A);
                wp_set_post_terms($example_article_id['ID'], $parent_term_id['term_id'], 'sldb_prtl_artikeltyp');

                add_option('initial_terms_added', 1);
        }

    }
    add_action( 'init', 'sldb_prtl_add_terms', 20 );
```